# Why is IP Address marked as deceptive site?

Tags: google-chrome, dns, malware

Google has determined that an IP address that I use is a “deceptive site” with possible phishing or other malware.

However, the status of the domain that points to said IP address is not.

I’ve used Google’s own tools to verify this discrepancy.

Why would this occur?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same and have no clue why. I reported the issue to Google, but it can be worrying for my users.